# How can i pass my two value through commandargument or another method in htmlgenericcontrol and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, command-line-arguments, htmlgenericcontrol

I write a function which creates imagebutton and I want to pass my id and subId when i click the imagebutton how can i do it . I tried to use commandargument method (  objImage.CommandArgument = id; ) but i cannot handle in imagebuttonclick function How can i call it and how can i pas id and sub id when i push imagebutton

```
 public HtmlGenericControl CreateDIV_OyVerme_Sub_Yildiz(string id, int subId)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl objDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        objDiv.ID = strControlName_DivYildiz + id + "_" + subId;

        objDiv.Attributes.Add("class", strClassName_DivYildiz);
        //objDiv.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        ImageButton objImage = new ImageButton();
        objImage.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

         ///////*******************
        objImage.CommandArgument = id; 
          ///***********


       objImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click);


        objImage.ID = strControlName_ImageYildiz + id +"_" + subId;
        objImage.ImageUrl = strImgSrc_yildiz;
        objImage.OnClientClick = strOnClientClickFunc_yildiz;
       // objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClick","WebForm4.amethod (o;"); 
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "19px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "20px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "0px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "relative");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "13px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, "6px");
        objImage.Style.Add("float", "left");
        objImage.ToolTip = subId + "/" + 5;
        // calling the method 
       // objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return(GetRssID(objRssItem));");

      //  var duck = objRssItem;

      //  objImage.Click += (s, e) => { WebForm4.amethod(objRssItem); };
       //objImage.Click += WebForm4.amethod (objRssItem); 

        objDiv.Controls.Add(objImage);

        return objDiv;
    }
```

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any attribute in HTML, e.g.

```
objImage.Attributes.Add("MyId", "Id");
objImage.Attributes.Add("MySubId", "SubId");
```

This can then be accessed in the click handler:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) {
    ImageButton objImage = (ImageButton) sender;
    var myId = objImage.Attributes["MyId"];
    var mySubId = objImage.Attributes["MySubId"];
}
```

Comment: how can i use it. in click method 
 public static void ImageButtons_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var myId = sender.Attributes["MyId"];
            

        }

Comment: Not sure why you have a click handler that  is static, or where it is in your code.  But if that event fires correctly when you click your ImageButton, it should work - try changing the "...void ImageButtons_Click(object sender, .." to ..void ImageButtons_Click(ImageButton sender, .."